# Angular: [(ngModel)] not working with <input type="time"> when only hours are set

Tags: html, angular

I have an input field in my html like following

```
   <input type="time"  name="abc" id="abc" [(ngModel)]="ab" >
   <div>{{ab}}</div>
```

Inside div element ab value shows up only when mins are selected along with hour

value of `ab` is undefined in this scenario
[image]

Value of ab shows in div when min is selected along with hour

[image]

How can I avoid value being undefined when minutes are not set,and set it to 00 by default?

Comment: You mean like this? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-starter-rew5qf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the default value from the beginning.

so in your component.ts do this,

```
this.ab = someDefaultValue;
```

in ngOnInit()/constructor()

here defaultValue can be same as you get when you set it to 00:00

Answer (score 0):

You can always set the value the value in the html similar to this way

```
 <input type="time" class="form-control" name="start-time" value={{setting.value}} (change)="onSettingChanged($event.target['value'])"/>
```

Also make sure you input name is unique otherwise ngModel won't work